# How to create Java file from JSON without creating a model Java file

Tags: java, json

For one of our current project, the requirement is, Java rest service will render the JSON output. To access that response everytime we have to create supported java model object. Instead of that, if we give the inputs are JSON response & the class name, by that is there any way to get the java files out of it.

for example, 
          WSDL2JAVA in maven or in any other way.

Comment: http://www.studytrails.com/java/json/java-google-json-parse-json-to-java/ ?

Comment: No, actually I am not gonna code for java model class files, that's the plan.

Comment: Can you post example json and how you would supply it to whatever?

Comment: http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org

Comment: @trooper, I am looking for exactly like this, but how can we do it in Java using any provided library.